# Odoo Server Error - External ID Not Found

Tags: odoo

I am facing an error that occurred on the Odoo server when installing hr_payroll_communty v13 in our odoo13. The error details are as follows:
I tried to install hr_payroll_community version 14 but it gives different error.  Since the current database is version 13, it is better to solve the problem for this version.

In addition, I installed bi_hr_payroll and it installed without any errors.  However, I developed custom modules for hr_payroll_community specifically.  So i need it to work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
r = d[key]
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in getitem
a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData.xmlid_lookup at 0x7f3b242999d8>, 'hr_payroll_community.module_category_hr_payroll_community')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 712, in parse
self._tag_root(de)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
f(rec)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
f(rec)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 561, in _tag_record
f_val = self.id_get(f_ref)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 657, in id_get
res = self.model_id_get(id_str, raise_if_not_found)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 663, in model_id_get
return self.env['ir.model.data'].xmlid_to_res_model_res_id(id_str, raise_if_not_found=raise_if_not_found)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1696, in xmlid_to_res_model_res_id
return self.xmlid_lookup(xmlid)[1:3]
File "<decorator-gen-25>", line 2, in xmlid_lookup
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 1685, in xmlid_lookup
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: hr_payroll_community.module_category_hr_payroll_community

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
raise value
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 915, in call
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/opt/odoo13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1343, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo13/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1331, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/opt/odoo13/odoo/api.py", line 387, in call_kw
The error message you provided indicates that there is an issue with an external ID in the Odoo system. The specific external ID that is causing the problem is "hr_payroll_community.module_category_hr_payroll_community". The system is unable to find this external ID, which is referenced in the code.
```

I created other test databases and it works.

Comment: Restart the server and try again. No reason for that error in the same file

Comment: I did and the problem presist.